# Overriding int on a bit enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I saw some .NET 2.0 code which looked like this:

```
 public enum abc : int
 {
  value1 = 1,
  value2 = 2,
  value3 = 4
 }
```

etc...

Now I know the flags enum can be used for bit values (like above, right?) so you can do | "or" &, etc, but what is the reason for not using that? What is the point in overriding int?

If I design an enum for choosing multiple values I would use the flags attribute and not override anything (what I don't understand). What does the above approach net?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not "overriding" `int`, it's indicating what type the enumeration is based on. The default is `int` so this actually isn't achieving anything, but in some cases you might want to base an enum on `long` to store more flags, or `byte` to save space if there will be very many instances of the enum around and it only has a few values, however the recommendation in the framework design guidelines is to use `int` unless you have a very good reason not to.

If this is intended to be a flags enumeration then it should be marked with `[Flags]`, and this appears to be the intention here, so the omission looks like a mistake. You can still combine the values using the bitwise operators even if it isn't marked with `[Flags]`, but from memory I think you get a compiler warning (or it might be an FxCop warning, or possibly a ReSharper warning...).

Answer (score 2):

The ": int" is specifying what to use as the underlying type for enum values; any integral type other than char can be used here.  The default is int, so it is redundant in this case.

Answer (score 2):

FlagsAttribute only tells the user that fields in this enum can be combined; it doesn't actually set the fields of the enum to "flaggable" values. This, you will have to do yourself, just like you have already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any benefit.  Probably lack of experience on the programmer's part.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking the scenario for choosing specific values, I don't know a good example offhand, but I can imagine something like

```
enum Color = {
  Red = 0xFF0000,
  Green = 0x00FF00,
  Blue = 0x0000FF }
```

maybe being useful.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the values on a non-Flags enum to use a 1-hot encoding just for the sake of using a 1-hot encoding doesn't really make any sense. I guess it might make sense if you thought you might make it a Flags enum in the future. Otherwise, the values should either be not overridden or assigned a value based on their meaning (eg. Color.Red = 0xFF0000).

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the ": int" specifying the underlying type, if I saw that, I'd have a look around and see if they delcare all their enums that way. If so, they probably just learnt to write enums that way ( or maybe they are a hyper-explicit coder). If however, just this enum was declared this way, perhaps the programmer is trying to say something (that might have been better said with a comment) that it is critical that this has an underlying "int" type. Perhaps it is being binary serialised or deserialised somewhere.

As for the [Flags] attribute, as far as C# is concerned, you can use bitwise operators on any enum, not just those declared with [Flags]. From your above example, without any [Flags], the following is totally legal:

abc myAbcValue = value1 | value2;

The primary difference with respect to the [Flags] is in the ToString() and Parse() methods of Enum. Without [Flags], myAbvValue.ToString() will return "3", but with [Flags] it will return "value1, value2". Likewise, with the [Flags],

abc yourAbcValue = (abc)Enum.Parse( typeof(abc), "value1, value2") ;

will set the underlying value of yourAbcValue to 3.

Note that the IsDefined() method of Enum() does not allow for multiple values with [Flags] enums, so:

Enum.IsDefined( typeof(abc), "value1, value2")

returns false regardless of the use of [Flags].

Also note that [Flags] provides information for any reflection access, and other languages may treat the restriction on flagged enums differntly to normal enums.